# How do I ensure my custom folder images look the same as the standard ones?

Tags: icons, directory, gui, display-resolution

I use Numix icon pack, and am trying to add custom folder icons, but when I add the from `/usr/share/icons` they are slightly larger and a little blurrier than the standard folder images.

I have tried using images from the 64 and 128 folders, but they both have this issue.

Here is a picture of the difference, I have manually added 'multi', whereas the others folders are standard, notice how they are smaller and sharper

[image]

How can I make the custom files look the same as the standard ones? Am I just choosing the wrong resolution?

Here are the resolution options afforded by Numix (scalable doesn't work).

[image]